# Compilation using native image is failing

Tags: graalvm

I have no idea why am getting this error. someone may have at least a clue please.

```
\[1/7\] Initializing...                                                                                    (0.0s @ 0.30GB)
Fatal error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.hashCode()" because "\<local2\>" is null
at com.oracle.svm.core.option.OptionOrigin.from(OptionOrigin.java:81)
at com.oracle.svm.core.option.LocatableMultiOptionValue.lambda$getValuesWithOrigins$1(LocatableMultiOptionValue.java:87)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
at com.oracle.svm.hosted.classinitialization.ClassInitializationFeature.processClassInitializationOptions(ClassInitializationFeature.java:82)
at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.setupNativeImage(NativeImageGenerator.java:812)
at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:554)
at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.run(NativeImageGenerator.java:514)
at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.buildImage(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:413)
at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.build(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:591)
at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:129)
at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner$JDK9Plus.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:621)
```

it fails where running gradle nativeCompile

MacBook Pro M1 chip.

```
openjdk version "17.0.3" 2022-04-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment GraalVM CE 22.1.0-dev (build 17.0.3+4-jvmci-22.1-b03)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM GraalVM CE 22.1.0-dev (build 17.0.3+4-jvmci-22.1-b03, mixed mode, sharing)
```

tried to change the GraalVM versions but no success.

Comment: just figured out that, for some reason the option buildArgs.add('--initialize-at-build-time=org.codehaus,org.jdbi.v3.core.config.JdbiCaches') is causing this NPE. Still need help on this.

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm running into the same crash

Comment: Yes, I did. You have to get the graalvm from oracle. Do not use the dev ones. https://github.com/graalvm/graalvm-ce-builds/releases/tag/vm-22.0.0.2